# Rails issue with either the relationship or the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to create a relationship in rails that seems to be causing some issues. I will also add this issue only seems to come up in the testing environment but the issue is we can't push new code with it failing.

We have the the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolled_minors
end
```

Minor

```
class Minor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolled_minors
end
```

Enrolled Minors

```
class EnrolledMinor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :minor
end
```

So a User has a minor (college minor) and that relationship is modeled through Enrolled Minors (also has more information omitted). Here is how I am creating an enrolled minor

```
@enrolled_minor = user.enrolled_minors.new(enrolled_minor_params)

def enrolled_minor_params
  params.require(:enrolled_minor).permit(:user_id, :minor_id)
end
```

Part of the Index view

```
- if @user.enrolled_minors.count > 0 || current_user.is_admin
  - @user.enrolled_minors.each do |em|
    = puts "user info: #{@user.inspect}"
    = puts "em: #{em.inspect}"
    = puts "manual-minor: #{Minor.find(em.minor_id).inspect}"
    = puts "em-minor: #{em.minor.inspect}"
    .minor-container data-enrolled-minor-id=em.id
      .minor-overview
        .container
          = render partial: 'dashboard/overview', locals: {em: em}
```

Partial showing a breakdown (fails on the h2 line)

```
- if em
  h2 #{em.minor.name}
```

Output from puts on index

```
user info: #<User id: 2, first_name: "user3", last_name: "last_name3",  created_at: "2017-01-10 02:35:36", updated_at: "2017-01-10 02:35:36">
em: #<EnrolledMinor id: 1, minor_accepted: nil, minor_completed: nil, user_id: 2, created_at: "2017-01-10 02:35:37", updated_at: "2017-01-10 02:35:37", minor_id: 2>
manual-minor: #<Minor id: 2, name: "minor4", nickname: "m4">
em-minor: nil
```

Stack Trace

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (ActionView::Template::Error)
  /Users/ajk292/Documents/code/rails/dyson-minors/app/views/dashboard/_overview.html.slim:2:in `_app_views_dashboard__overview_html_slim__2246120880992646294_70207059823680'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/Documents/code/rails/dyson-minors/app/views/dashboard/index.html.slim:10:in `block in _app_views_dashboard_index_html_slim__906501886411520268_70207062528140'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
  /Users/ajk292/Documents/code/rails/dyson-minors/app/views/dashboard/index.html.slim:2:in `_app_views_dashboard_index_html_slim__906501886411520268_70207062528140'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  /Users/ajk292/Documents/code/rails/dyson-minors/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:13:in `show'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/cucumber-rails-1.4.2/lib/cucumber/rails/action_controller.rb:10:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/request_store-1.3.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capybara-2.5.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/ajk292/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

So What I've worked it out to be is that I think the issue is somehow the relationship is not being created between a minor and an enrolled minor. There is a reference and I can "manually" find it by using the find function and the id stored. Also as I said this happens when running test but not on dev. If I go to the page after enrolling in a new minor from the web development server it is successful.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I wonder how your test are being performed BUT I can tell you that the parent object could be cached, that's very common when testing. Try adding a reload to the collection as `@user.enrolled_minors.reload` and then check for values in the associations.

Comment: Hiya - any chance you can give us the line-number that's failing? Or at least... where is `name` being called? Stacktrace perhaps? Also... `@user` or `user` ? are they the same thing? where does that happen? (just checking)  If it only fails in test env that's usually a case of mocks/stubs not being really created/saved in the db... look to see if something used `new` but not `create` (eg the current_user)

Comment: The place it is failing is in the partial at H2 where it tries to get the name. Yes they are basically the same. There was a point where I used user instead of @user. Also the reloading didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify the :inverse_of option on your associations to make sure different versions of the same object aren't loaded into memory.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolled_minors, inverse_of: :user
end

class Minor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolled_minors, inverse_of: :minor
end 

class EnrolledMinor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :enrolled_minors
  belongs_to :minor, inverse_of: :enrolled_minors
end
```

Then, when building on the user's enrolled_minor association you probably don't want to be allowing the user_id parameter to be set too, since it would override the user from the association, so

```
def user_built_enrolled_minor_params
  params.require(:enrolled_minor).permit(:minor_id)
end
```

and then either

```
#build linked EnrolledMinor but don't save
@enrolled_minor = user.enrolled_minors.build(user_built_enrolled_minor_params)

#build linked EnrolledMinor and save
@enrolled_minor = user.enrolled_minors.create(user_built_enrolled_minor_params)
```